# design question for transportation agency/workflow system

Tags: 2007, workflow

I am designing a transportation agency/workflow system, and I am wondering whether using SharePoint 2007 could facilitate my development process?

Here is a brief introduction of the system. The system including 3 roles of people, customer who requests to transport some stuff, drivers who deliver the stuff, and truck manager who manages transport source/destination truck coordination and communicates/organizes drivers.

The system is expected to be a web site, and 3 kinds of people could use the web site to submit request, accept request, monitor status of specific stuff transportation, etc. The web site is more like an open agency or a workflow system.

My question is, whether I could base my application on SharePoint 2007, and if yes, more details about how SharePoint could facilitate/speed-up my system design/implementation (e.g. some existing features of SharePoint 2007 could be used instead of developing from scratch using ASP.Net + IIS)? Appreciate if any online system which is similar to my application based on SharePoint, so that I can make a quick reference. :-)

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

George have you looked into one of the 40 fabulous templates?
Sharepoint should easily work for that.You might to even need to use a workflow maybe it could just be needed when you want to send a confirmation email.

Comment: Which template is more suitable for me? Any reference samples online?

Comment: Any new ideas or updates? :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a Sharepoint 2007 implementation the above scenario can easily captured using Sharepoint WorkFlow

Comment: Which workflow model is most suitable for me? And any reference samples online?

Comment: Any new ideas or updates? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at incorporating Infopath forms with custom views.  You can create different sections based on which group the user is a member of.  Design three AD groups (general users, drivers, managers) and then set to your form views.  For bonus points, you can also use these groups to customize content display using SharePoint audiences.